# Django foreignkey and tables one to many relationship

Tags: python, sql, django

I am new to Django and python and I have been following the Django tutorial to build a personal project.

So far I have been able to do it without major problems, but have got stuck in the creation of the models.py when I need more than one table and need to build relationship with them.

I have two tables: one related to a product list and another one related to average prices for those types of products

I basically want to get the records of table 2 and add the average price for them which is stored in table 1, and the join must be done using 3 fields: model, year and size.

When I query only the products table (2), I do it as

```
latest_products = Products.objects.all().order_by('-date_added')
```

How could I get also the average price for each product from the average price table inside this query?

I have already read the documentation and many posts here but still have this mess in my

table 1 (average price)

```
class Avg_price(models.Model):
  model = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  size= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  year= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  price= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

table 2 (product list)

```
class Products(models.Model):
  product_id =models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
  date_added= models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  model = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  size= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  year= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  price= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)      
  avg_price=models.ForeignKey(Avg_price)
```

Sorry if this questions might sound dumb... and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a `Products` instance, you also have their related `Avg_price`. Check this out:

```
>>> my_product = latest_products[0]
>>> print my_product.avg_price.year
"prints my_product's price's year"
```

Alternatively, you could use [`.select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) queryset method:

```
products_prices = Products.objects.all().select_realted('avg_price')
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: It did not... sorry if I am missing something... what I really need is the price field from the table avg_price, in this case I tried latest_products.avg_price.price but got nothing... also how does django knows that I want the join to be made in the 3 fields (size, year and model)? thanks for the help!

Comment: The query do not return an error but when I try to get the field price from the table Avg_price in the template I do not get anything (latest_products.avg_price.price)...

Comment: check if `latest_products.avg_price.price is None`

Comment: So everything works fine, it's just that the avg_price's price has not been set yet.